# MacOSXでホスト名が勝手に（自動で）変わってしまう

Tags: macos

- OSX 10.10.1
- Timemachine使用

Yosemiteにアップデート後からかは不明ですが、
最近ホスト名が勝手に変わってしまいます。

`macbookpro.local`としていたものが、

`macbookpro-2.local`にいつの間にか変わってました。

これでここ２週間で２度めです。

- Time capsule のWifiを使用
- WifiはONですが、有線LANも使用

どうやら、Timemachineのバックアップ後に変わっているタイミングに感じます。
同じような現象の方いらっしゃいませんか。

対策を知りたいです。

Comment: 以前同じ現象になりました。[osx - How do I stop my computer name from automatically, and incorrectly, changing? - Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125411/how-do-i-stop-my-computer-name-from-automatically-and-incorrectly-changing)これと同様の現象でしょうか。WiFiか有線LANどちらかをオフにすればいいようですが、根本的な解決方法は不明です。

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OSXのホスト名は３つあり

```
sudo scutil --get ComputerName
sudo scutil --get HostName
sudo scutil --get LocalHostName
```

で取得できます。どれかが設定されていないのかもしれません。

それぞれ設定するには

```
sudo scutil --set ComputerName newName
sudo scutil --set HostName newName
sudo scutil --set LocalHostName newName
```

です。私はいつも３つともドメインの含まない同じ名前にしていますが、
試してみてはいかがでしょう。

Comment: $ sudo scutil --get HostName
HostName: not set
でHostNameだけセットされてませんでした。

HostNameを設定して様子見してみます。
ちなみに.localはローカルホスト名の設定欄に固定である分でした。

なのでホスト名はmacbookproのみでした。

Comment: 回答の設定以後、12/12現在まで発生していません。この設定で解消すると思います。

Answer (score 2):

Bonjour名はネットワーク上に同一のものがあると、自動的に末尾に番号をつけて重複を回避する挙動をします。$ arp -aしてみて、ARPテーブルに残骸が残っているようであれば $ arp -dしてみると良いかもしれません。

＞　質問者です

$ arp -a すると以下のようになりました。
（詳しくないので） 192.168.24.1で何か重複しているような雰囲気ですが、ここあたりですかね？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: あ。それっぽいですね。一度$ arp -dしておくと良いと思います。

Answer (score 2):

私も同じ現象になりましたが、<strike>spindle</strike> .sparsebundle ファイルを削除して再バックアップしたところ、発生しなくなりました。

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2013)
- OS X 10.10.1
- TimeMachine Wifi 経由で週1回バックアップ

Comment: spindle？どのように削除するのですか？

Comment: 失礼しました。.sparsebundle です。マウントしている TimeCapsule から直接削除しました。当然過去のバックアップがすべて消えてしまいますのでご注意ください。

[link]https://discussionsjapan.apple.com/message/100586164

Answer (score 2):

私も過去にたようなことがありました。ただ、ずいぶん昔のことだったので詳細は忘れてしまいましたが、その時は Ethernet と Wi-Fi 両方で同じルータに接続していたことが起因していたと記憶しています。

その時は固定IPで、Ethernet と Wi-Fi 両方同じIPにすることで回避しました。